# Allow derived class objects to by created only by specific interface

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a class like so:

```
class A
{
public:
   template <class T> static inline T* Create()
   {
      static_assert(std::is_base_of<A, T>::value);
      return new T;
   }
protected:
   A();
   virtual ~A();
}
```

The goal is all objects of classes that derive from "A" to be created only on the heap. This code will work for objects of type A, since the destructor is not public, but nothing stops the creation of an derived class that creates a public destructor.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why impose such a restriction at the code level?

Comment: Move the factory function out of the base class to a free function. Make this free function a `friend` of the classes it needs to instantiate. Make the constructors of these classes `private`. Verify compliance with code review. Recommendation: Forget about `new`. Return `std::unique_ptr<A>` and get the allocation with `std::make_unique`. This simple change has the potential to save you days of debugging.

Comment: The restriction of being on the heap smells of a bigger design issue at play. The only singular reason I can think of to restrict construction to be a specific type of allocation would be for for types using `std::shared_from_this` -- which, generally speaking, should be an abstracted implementation detail.